# iOS use parsed Json and put into TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, wcf, uitableview

I'm very new to both Obj-c and json, I'm creating my first iOS project using a TableViewController. The json I got from the WCF looks like this:

```
{
Fri =     (
    "\U8fc7\U7a0b\U63a7\U5236\U7cfb\U7edf\U4e0e\U4eea\U8868;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c1,2\U8282{\U7b2c7-16\U5468};\U9ad8\U5b8f\U4f1f;XX-226",
    "MATLAB\U5e94\U7528;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c3,4\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U8d75\U5ef6\U4e1c;XX-128;;\U8ba1\U7b97\U673a\U8fc7\U7a0b\U63a7\U5236\U6280\U672f;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c3,4\U8282{\U7b2c1-8\U5468};\U9ad8\U5b8f\U4f1f;XX-226",
    "\U7f51\U7edc\U5316\U6d4b\U63a7\U7cfb\U7edf;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c5,6\U8282{\U7b2c1-12\U5468};\U80e1\U745e/\U9648\U4eae;XX-228",
    "\U5de5\U63a7\U7ec4\U6001\U8f6f\U4ef6\U53ca\U5e94\U7528;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c7,8\U8282{\U7b2c1-8\U5468};\U9a6c\U666f\U5bcc;XX-228;;\U81ea\U52a8\U63a7\U5236\U539f\U7406\Uff08\U63d0\U9ad8\Uff09;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c7,8\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U5218\U6d77\U8273;XX-229",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
);
Mon =     (
    "\U5d4c\U5165\U5f0f\U4eea\U8868\U8bbe\U8ba1\U57fa\U7840;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c1,2\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U5218\U519b/\U77f3\U5f81\U9526;XX-229",
    "\U7535\U5b50\U6d4b\U91cf\U6280\U672f;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c3,4\U8282{\U7b2c1-16\U5468};\U8d75\U4e9a\U5a01/\U9ad8\U5b8f\U4f1f;XX-130",
    "\U4fe1\U53f7\U4e0e\U7cfb\U7edf\Uff08\U63d0\U9ad8\Uff09;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c5,6\U8282{\U7b2c1-8\U5468};\U534e\U5b87\U5b81;XX-130;;\U53ef\U7f16\U7a0b\U63a7\U5236\U5668;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c5,6\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U66f2\U4e07\U6625;XX-336",
    "\U667a\U80fd\U4eea\U5668\U4eea\U8868;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c7,8\U8282{\U7b2c1-12\U5468};\U66f2\U4e07\U6625;XX-336",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
);}
```

And what I did with this Json is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"JSONRead";
NSString *testUrl = @"testurl";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:testUrl];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:10];

NSData *JSONData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSArray *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
self.str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.data = jsonResult;

NSMutableDictionary *dJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"DictionaryJson is %@",dJSON);
NSMutableArray *_names=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id item in jsonResult)
    [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item]];;
self.names = _names;
NSLog(@"%@", self.names);

   }
```

And what comes into this `NSMutableArray names` is only Fri and Mon that has showed in the TableView. What I wanna ask is, how to show the other information in the tableview as well? Or how to add all those info into the `NSMutableArray names`? Like this form, those lines in different TableView Cells, not in the same one

```
Fri
\U8fc7\U7a0b\U63a7\U5236\U7cfb\U7edf\U4e0e\U4eea\U8868;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c1,2\U8282{\U7b2c7-16\U5468};\U9ad8\U5b8f\U4f1f;XX-226
MATLAB\U5e94\U7528;\U5468\U4e94\U7b2c3,4\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U8d75\U5ef6\U4e1c;XX-128
```

......

```
Mon
\U5d4c\U5165\U5f0f\U4eea\U8868\U8bbe\U8ba1\U57fa\U7840;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c1,2\U8282{\U7b2c9-16\U5468};\U5218\U519b/\U77f3\U5f81\U9526;XX-229
U7535\U5b50\U6d4b\U91cf\U6280\U672f;\U5468\U4e00\U7b2c3,4\U8282{\U7b2c1-16\U5468};\U8d75\U4e9a\U5a01/\U9ad8\U5b8f\U4f1f;XX-130
```

......

Thanks very much, I would post pics if I could, but I can't...Sorry about that...and Thanks for the answers

**Also, I didn't mean that those `xxx,xxxx` to show in one row...  I want them to show in different TableViewCells if possible, or show in different rows in one cells if there's no better solution. So adding them into a single NSString isn't the solution I'm looking for...  Sorry**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution..

```
for (id item in jsonResult)
    {
    NSArray *array=[jsonResult valueForKey:item];
    NSString *joinedComponents = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    [_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", item,joinedComponents]];;
    self.names = _names;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.names);
    }
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Yes, that does add those info into the table view, the problem is, it's not independent.They are in the same cells and I'd like to put them in different cells. Any ideas?